# Is BigQuery possible to assign more than 10 thousands paremeters at `IN` query?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I defined following schema in BigQuery

```
[
 {
    "mode": "REQUIRED",
    "name": "customer_id",
    "type": "STRING"
 },
 {
    "mode": "REPEATED",
    "name": "segments",
    "type": "RECORD",
    "fields": [
        {
            "mode": "REQUIRED",
            "name": "segment_id",
            "type": "STRING"
        }
    ]
 }
]
```

I try to insert a new segment_id to specific customer ids something like this:

```
#standardSQL
UPDATE `sample-project.customer_segments.segments`
SET segments = ARRAY(
  SELECT segment FROM UNNEST(segments) AS segment
  UNION ALL
  SELECT STRUCT('NEW_SEGMENT')
)
WHERE customer_id IN ('0000000000', '0000000001', '0000000002')
```

Is it possible to assign more than 10 thousands cusomer_id to `IN` query at BigQuery?

Comment: haven't you tried? isn't that something that just easy to try and see result? meantime see my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to assign more than 10 thousands cusomer_id to IN query at BigQuery?

Assuming (based on example in your question) the length of customer_id is around 10 chars plus three chars for apostrophes and comma you will and up with extra around 130KB which is within limit of 250KB (see more in [Quotas & Limits](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#query_jobs))

So, you should be fine with 10K and easily can calculate the limit - looks like limit will go around 19K

Just to clarify:

I meant below limitations (mostly first one)

> Maximum unresolved query length — 256 KB
>
> Maximum resolved query length — 12 MB

Comment: I checked `Quotas & Limits` you mentioned. and I knew I can calculate the limit ! Thank you very much, Mikhail.

Answer (score 1):

When working with a long list of possible values, it's a good idea to use a [query parameter](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/parameterized-queries#using_arrays_in_parameterized_queries) instead of inlining the entire list into the query, assuming you are working with the command line client or API. For example,

```
#standardSQL
UPDATE `sample-project.customer_segments.segments`
SET segments = ARRAY(
  SELECT segment FROM UNNEST(segments) AS segment
  UNION ALL
  SELECT STRUCT('NEW_SEGMENT')
)
WHERE customer_id IN UNNEST(@customer_ids)
```

Here you would create a query parameter of type `ARRAY<STRING>` containing the customer IDs.